# Homeomorphism between $X$ and $X \times X$ with different topologies

Tags: general-topology, inverse-function

I have to solve this problem subdivided in three parts:

1. Let $X$ be an infinite set with the discrete topology. Prove that $X$ is homeomorphic to $X\times X$.
2. If $X$ has the trivial topology, is it still true that $X$ is homeomorphic to $X\times X$?
3. Find another example of a space $X$ homeomorphic to $X\times X$ in which $X$ has not the trivial topology neither the discrete one.

I tried to solve it in this way:

1. Let's define the homeomorphism $$\phi: X \to X\times X \\ x \mapsto (x,x)$$ In this way every open set in $X\times X$ is mapped to an open set through $\phi^{-1}$ because $X$ has the discrete topology in which every subsset is open
2. I would use the previous homeomorphism because the unique open set which contains $(x,x)$ is $X\times X$ and $\phi^{-1}$ maps $X\times X$ in $X$ which is the unique open set which contains $X$.

Is my reasoning right?

3. For this question I have no idea how to proceed. I know that I cannot use the euclidean topology because, for example, $\mathbb{R}$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$. Have you any ideas?

Comment: No, your reasoning is not sound. A homeomorphism is bijective and the function defined by you is not.

Comment: The title is confusing and making it seem as though $X$ has one type of topology, and $X\times X$ a different one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1. Let $X$ be an infinite set with the discrete topology. Prove that $X$ is homeomorphic to $X\times X$.

Unfortunately your $\phi: x\mapsto (x,x)$ **is not** a homeomorphism. The $\phi^{-1}$ simply doesn't exist because $\phi$ is not onto. For example if $a\neq b$ then there is no $x$ such that $\phi(x)=(a,b)$.

To solve that problem you need some set theoretic background, namely:

> **Lemma 1.** Let $X$ be an infinite set. Then there exists a bijection $f:X\to X\times X$.

You can find a proof for that in some set theoretic books. That is not trivial at all. Note that it doesn't have to be a homeomorphism (and indeed, in some cases it cannot be, for example when $X=\mathbb{R}$ as you've noted yourself). There's no notion of topology in the lemma above.

Now we take another important fact:

> **Lemma 2.** Let $X,Y$ be two discrete spaces. Then any function $f:X\to Y$ is continuous.

I leave as an exercise. Note that Lemma 2 applies to trivial topologies as well. Combining these two we have:

> **Corollary.** Any infinite discrete space $X$ is homeomorphic to $X\times X$.

---

> 2. If $X$ has the trivial topology, is it still true that $X$ is homeomorphic to $X\times X$?

For the trivial topology note that $X$ has exactly two open subsets: $\emptyset, X$. How many open subsets $X\times X$ has? Since every open subset in product topology is of the form $\bigcup U\times V$ then we can easily verify that a nonempty combination of $\emptyset$ and $X$ can only give $X\times X$. Meaning topology on $X\times X$ is trivial. Combining it with Lemma 1 easily shows that they have to be homeomorphic.

---

> 3. Find another example of a space $X$ homeomorphic to $X\times X$ in which $X$ has not the trivial topology neither the discrete one.

One such example would be rationals $\mathbb{Q}$ with Euclidean topology. This is due to

> **Theorem (Sierpiński).** Every countable, metrizable space without isolated points is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. What if I try with the following homeomorphism?  $$\phi: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}  \times \mathbb{N} \\ 2^m(2n+1)-1 \mapsto (m,n)$$ and for the third question can I use $$\phi: \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}  \times \mathbb{Q} \\ \frac{p}{q} \mapsto (p,q)$$ where MCD(p,q)=1 ?

Comment: @Phi_24 For the third one with $\mathbb{Q}$ the homeomorphism is not easily given explicitly, it follows from the Sierpinski theorem. For the first two any bijection between $X$ and $X \times X$ will do (and you cannot give an explicit one for arbitary infinite $X$, but for explicitly countable ones it's easy). Your second $\phi$ is not well-defined anyway.

Comment: @Phi_24 Your first function is ok, but it works only for $\mathbb{N}$, not general infinite $X$. Your second one is not ok. For example try solving $\phi(x)=(1/2, 1)$. The image of your $\phi$ is $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ unfortunately. Finding a homeomorphism $\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$ is far from trivial.

Comment: @Phi_24 The fact that $\mathbb Q$ is homeomorphic to its square is too difficult for a student at your level. If you are familiar with infinite products of topological spaces, the most natural example is the Cantor space, the product of infinitely many copies of the space $\{0,1\}$ with the discrete topology. Less natural but even easier, let $X$ be an infinite set with the discrete topology, and let $Y$ be an infinite set with the trivial topology; then $X\times Y$ is homeomorphic to $(X\times Y)\times (X\times Y).$

Comment: @bof thank you for your comment, but the third question requested a unique set X without using discrete nor trivial topology.

Comment: @Phi_24 If $X_1$ is an infinite space with discrete topology, and $X_2$ is an infinite space with trivial topology, then the product space $X=X_1\times X_2$ is a unique space whose topology is neither discrete nor trivial, and $X$ is homeomorphic to $X.$ That's all question 3 asked for. You didn't say anything about not "USING" a trivial or discrete topology, whatever that means. (I think it would be hard to define precisely. So now you are changing the question. I guess you don't like the Cantor set example either, since it's homeomorphic to a product of discrete spaces.

Comment: @Phi_24 All right, how about $X=\mathbb R^\omega,$ the product of infinitely many copies of the real line? Nothine discrete or trivial about that, and $X\times X$ is obviously homeomorphic to $X.$ Or let $X=$ Hilbert space.